# How can a function get access to itself?

Tags: javascript

Is it right, that when the 'inner' function is called in the example that I gave, the JS engine looks for the declaration of the 'inner' function in the current scope(now it is the scope of the 'inner' function). Since there is no declaration of it in the current scope, the JS engine is trying to find the 'inner' function declaration in the outer scope, and the outer scope is exactly the place where the 'inner' function was declared. So is it correct to say, that the 'inner' function can call itself because the scope chain was used?

```
function outer() {
    function inner() {
        inner();
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to give much more information about what you are trying to do

Comment: Your recursive call to `inner()` is made within the scope of the function. `Scope` is what "gives access" to reference a variable/function

Comment: Just in case you have a little confusion: `Scope` and `Context` are different things. Scope is what your function can see, what vars are accessible, this is what gives access to `inner` in `outer`. The context (`this`, the function object as you're calling it), is a different thing, not involved in your case

Comment: No.  It can call itself because it is within the same scope as err.... itself.  Under the simplest of circumstances, every function inside `outer(){}` can execute every other function inside `outer(){}`, because they are within the same scope.  Any code outside `outer(){}` cannot access those functions (again, under the most default of circumstances - all these things can be made to change).

Comment: @mplungjan, sorry, I think my question is unclear. What I wanted to say is that when the 'inner' function is called in the example that I gave, the JS engine looks for the declaration of the 'inner' function in the current scope(now it is the scope of the 'inner' function). Since there is no declaration of it in the current scope, the JS engine is trying to find the 'inner' function declaration in the outer scope, and the outer scope is exactly the place where the 'inner' function was declared. So is it correct to say, that the 'inner' function can call itself because the scope chain was used?

Comment: i can't confirm right now but i think it's rather an internal Javascript feature that allows a function to be available in itself, because it has its own Errors for that, like "Too many recursions etc". So it actually detects it's recursion, not simple scope access.

Answer (score 0):

The outer function is irrelevant for the example given. The following would also work:

```
function inner() {
    inner();
}
```

So, no. It doesn't get access via the outer function.

Comment: I'm not sure of the real question but `inner` **is** defined in the scope of `outer`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret But `inner` is not able to access itself because of `outer`.

Answer (score 0):

what i know is that calling itself will create a new place in the memory, so it's another copy(or lets say *kind of* instance) from itself, but with another copy of every variable inside it, saying:

```
function outer() {
    function inner(params) {
        //ignore existance of the stop condition
        //at first call params is 3 then it will be 2
        inner(2);
    }
    inner(3)
}
```

each one has it's own place in memory and it's own variables